# Will unsealed fish in the freezer contaminate packaged food?

Tags: fish

My step dad put 3 unsealed fishes from the lake in the freezer.  I also have  sealed waffles and sealed hotdog meat in the freezer.  I want to make sure the package food is safe for my children to eat.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE.  What do you mean by "unsealed"? Are the fish resting on something (like a cookie sheet), or are they just tossed into the freezer without anything?

Answer (score 2):

In the freezer, things are relatively safe, as pathogens will not multiply given the cold temperature.  So, as long as you remove the package with the waffles and toast, or remove the hotdog package and cook, you will be fine. There is a higher risk for pathogens to multiply on anything that the fish is resting on if you were to remove those items and warm them up slowly (thaw on the counter top, for example). There is also a risk of cross contamination if you have the handle the fish to move things about.  However, the more significant problem with not wrapping the fish is (a) it will dehydrate/become "freezer burned" thus limiting shelf life, (b) it will be a source of off-flavors for other food stored in the refrigerator/freezer, and (c) it will pick up off-flavors from the rest of your refrigerator/freezer.